# Issue related to Reading Excel using Apache POI in java

Tags: java, excel, apache, aspose-cells

I am trying to create an excel file of 2007.
Scenario for Creation of Excel from other file.

Input file       :- InputFile.xlsx with One Sheet

Calculation File :- Model.xlsx with four sheets

Description for Calculation file :- 1) First Sheet is input file
2) Second sheet is Output 3) Third and Fourth Sheet is calculation sheets.

in Java using Apache POI I am reading Excel file. in one function I am reading file,takes input files `InputFiles.xlsx`

in second function I am merging two sheets in `model.xlsx` file. i.e.in the first sheet of `Model.xlsx` merging first sheet of `InputFile.xlsx`

In third function I am reading output, that affect after writing in `model.xlsx` and reading it.

`Merging function as follows`

```
        public void writeXLSXFile(String modelid, String inputfile) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException
            {
                try
                {
                    String realPath = context.getRealPath("/");
                    String DestPath = "";
                    InputStream ExcelFileToRead = new FileInputStream(inputfile);

                    XSSFWorkbook wbip = new XSSFWorkbook(ExcelFileToRead);

                    DestPath = realPath + "WEB-INF/classes/uploadfiles/Model.xlsx";

                    NPOIFSFileSystem fs = new NPOIFSFileSystem(new File(DestPath));
                    EncryptionInfo info = new EncryptionInfo(fs);
                    Decryptor d = Decryptor.getInstance(info);
                    XSSFWorkbook wb = null;
                    try
                    {
                        if (d.verifyPassword("MUSDCM"))
                        {
                            wb = new XSSFWorkbook(d.getDataStream(fs));
                        } else
                        {
                            System.out.println("Wrong Password");
                        }
                    } catch (GeneralSecurityException ex)
                    {
                    }

                    XSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
                    wb.removeSheetAt(0);
                    wb.removeSheetAt(3);

                    wb.createSheet("2.2 Parameter Estimates");
                    wb.createSheet("Raw Macro Data");

                    wb.setSheetOrder("DCM_Implementation_v09.csv", 1);
                    wb.setSheetOrder("Excel Model_IG", 2);
                    wb.setSheetOrder("Excel Model_HY", 3);
                    wb.setSheetOrder("Raw Macro Data", 4);
                    wb.setSheetOrder("2.2 Parameter Estimates", 0);
                    sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);

                    XSSFRow row = sheet.createRow(1);
                    XSSFCell cell = row.createCell(1);
                    cell.setCellValue("Investment Grade Bond Issuance Volume Model");
                    cell = row.createCell(4);
                    cell.setCellValue("High Yield Bond Issuance Volume Model");

                    row = sheet.createRow(3);
                    cell = row.createCell(1);
                    cell.setCellValue("Independent Variables");
                    cell = row.createCell(2);
                    cell.setCellValue("Coefficients");

                    cell = row.createCell(4);
                    cell.setCellValue("Independent Variables");
                    cell = row.createCell(5);
                    cell.setCellValue("Coefficients");

                    int rowNumber = 4;

                    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                    Connection con = getConnection();
                    Statement st = con.createStatement();
                    ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT s.volumename,s.id,s.parameter,s.value,m.model_name FROM singlevalue_table s inner join model_inventory m on s.modelid =m.modelid and s.modelid=" + modelid);
                    ArrayList InBond = new ArrayList();
                    ArrayList HnBond = new ArrayList();
                    while (rs.next())
                    {
                        if ("Investment Grade Bond Issuance Volume Model".equals(rs.getString("s.volumename")))
                        {
                            InBond.add(rs.getString("s.parameter"));
                            InBond.add(rs.getString("s.value"));
                        } else if ("High Yield Bond Issuance Volume Model".equals(rs.getString("s.volumename")))
                        {
                            HnBond.add(rs.getString("s.parameter"));
                            HnBond.add(rs.getString("s.value"));
                        }
                    }
                    int maxcount = ((InBond.size() >= HnBond.size()) ? InBond.size() : HnBond.size());
                    int count1 = 0;
                    int count2 = 0;
                    for (int j = 0; j < maxcount / 2; j++)
                    {
                        row = sheet.createRow(j + 4);
                        if (j < (InBond.size() / 2))
                        {
                            cell = row.createCell(1);
                            cell.setCellValue((String) InBond.get(count1));
                            cell = row.createCell(2);
                            cell.setCellValue((String) InBond.get(count1 + 1));
                            count1 += 2;
                        }
                        if (j < (HnBond.size() / 2))
                        {
                            cell = row.createCell(4);
                            cell.setCellValue((String) HnBond.get(count2));
                            cell = row.createCell(5);
                            cell.setCellValue((String) HnBond.get(count2 + 1));
                            count2 += 2;
                        }
                    }
                    wb = CopySheet(wbip, wb);
                    try
                    {
                        wb.setForceFormulaRecalculation(true);
                        FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(DestPath);
                        wb.write(fileOut);
                        wbip.close();
                        wb.close();
                        fs.close();
                        fileOut.close();
                    } catch (IOException e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    //Add password protection and encrypt the file
                    fs = null;
                    info = null;
                    fs = new NPOIFSFileSystem();
                    info = new EncryptionInfo(fs, EncryptionMode.binaryRC4);

                    Encryptor enc = info.getEncryptor();
                    enc.confirmPassword("MUSDCM");

                    OPCPackage opc = OPCPackage.open(new File(DestPath), PackageAccess.READ_WRITE);
                    OutputStream os = enc.getDataStream(fs);
                    opc.save(os);
                    opc.close();

                    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(DestPath);
                    fs.writeFilesystem(fos);
                    fos.close();
                    fs.close();
                    ExcelFileToRead.close();
                    System.out.println("File created!!");
                } catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Logger.getLogger(resource.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }
```

`Reading output from Model.xlsx function as follows`

```
            public Response readXLSXFileWithSecondSheet(@QueryParam("modelid") String modelid) throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException
                {
                    try
                    {
                        String realPath = context.getRealPath("/");
                        String DestPath = realPath + "WEB-INF/classes/uploadfiles/DCM_Implementation_v10.xlsx";
                        NPOIFSFileSystem fs = new NPOIFSFileSystem(new File(DestPath));
                        EncryptionInfo info = new EncryptionInfo(fs);
                        Decryptor d = Decryptor.getInstance(info);
                        XSSFWorkbook wb = null;
                        if (d.verifyPassword("MUSDCM"))
                        {
                            wb = new XSSFWorkbook(d.getDataStream(fs));
                            wb.setForceFormulaRecalculation(true);
                        } else
                        {
                            System.out.println("Wrong Password");
                        }
                        XSSFSheet sheet = (XSSFSheet) wb.getSheetAt(1);
                        XSSFRow row;
                        XSSFCell cell;
                        ArrayList Heading = new ArrayList();
                        ArrayList<graphdata> Basemap = new ArrayList<graphdata>();
                        ArrayList<graphdata> Adversemap = new ArrayList<graphdata>();
                        ArrayList<graphdata> SeverelyAdversemap = new ArrayList<graphdata>();
                        ArrayList<graphdata> BHCBasemap = new ArrayList<graphdata>();
                        ArrayList<graphdata> BHCSeverelyAdversemap = new ArrayList<graphdata>();
                        String ModelName = "Investment Grade Bond Issuance Volume Model";
                        Iterator rows = sheet.rowIterator();
                        while (rows.hasNext())
                        {
                            row = (XSSFRow) rows.next();
                            Iterator cells = row.cellIterator();
                            //int columnNo = 1;
                            int CCARCount = 0;
                            graphdata g1 = new graphdata();
                            graphdata g2 = new graphdata();
                            graphdata g3 = new graphdata();
                            graphdata g4 = new graphdata();
                            graphdata g5 = new graphdata();
                            while (cells.hasNext())
                            {
                                cell = (XSSFCell) cells.next();
                                int ActulaColINdex = cell.getColumnIndex();

                                if (cell.getCellType() == XSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK)
                                {

                                    continue;
                                }

                                if (cell.getCellType() == XSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_STRING)
                                {
                                    if (((String) cell.getRichStringCellValue().getString()).equals(ModelName) && cell.getColumnIndex() == 1)
                                    {
                                        ModelName = (String) cell.getRichStringCellValue().getString();
                                        continue;
                                    }
                                    if (((String) cell.getRichStringCellValue().getString()).equals("High Yield Bond Issuance Volume Model") && cell.getColumnIndex() == 1)
                                    {
                                        ModelName = (String) cell.getRichStringCellValue().getString();
                                        continue;
                                    }

                                    String FindCCAR = (String) cell.getRichStringCellValue().getString();
                                    if (FindCCAR.contains("CCAR"))
                                    {
                                        continue;
                                    }
                                    if (FindCCAR.contains("CCAR"))
                                    {
                                        switch (CCARCount)
                                        {
                                            case 0:
                                                Heading.add(FindCCAR);
                                                break;
                                            case 1:
                                                Heading.add(FindCCAR);
                                                break;
                                            case 2:
                                                Heading.add(FindCCAR);
                                                break;
                                            case 3:
                                                Heading.add(FindCCAR);
                                                break;
                                            case 4:
                                                Heading.add(FindCCAR);
                                                break;
                                        }
                                        CCARCount++;
                                    }
                                    if (FindCCAR.contains("Date") || FindCCAR.contains("Model") || FindCCAR.contains("Diff"))
                                    {
                                        continue;
                                    }

                                    if (ActulaColINdex <= 5 && ActulaColINdex >= 1) //Base 
                                    {
                                        if (ActulaColINdex == 1)
                                        {
                                            g1.setVolumeName(ModelName);
                                            g1.setModelName("Base");
                                            g1.setYear(cell.getRichStringCellValue().toString());
                                        }
                                        //System.out.print(cell.getRichStringCellValue() + " ");

                                    }
                                    if (ActulaColINdex <= 11 && ActulaColINdex >= 7) //Adverse 
                                    {
                                        if (ActulaColINdex == 7)
                                        {
                                            g2.setVolumeName(ModelName);
                                            g2.setModelName("Adverse");
                                            g2.setYear(cell.getRichStringCellValue().toString());
                                        }
                                        //System.out.print(cell.getRichStringCellValue() + " ");

                                    }
                                    if (ActulaColINdex <= 17 && ActulaColINdex >= 13) //Severly Adverse 
                                    {
                                        if (ActulaColINdex == 13)
                                        {
                                            g3.setVolumeName(ModelName);
                                            g3.setModelName("Severely Adverse");
                                            g3.setYear(cell.getRichStringCellValue().toString());
                                        }
                                        //System.out.print(cell.getRichStringCellValue() + " ");

                                    }
                                    if (ActulaColINdex <= 23 && ActulaColINdex >= 19) //BHC Base 
                                    {
                                        if (ActulaColINdex == 19)
                                        {
                                            g4.setVolumeName(ModelName);
                                            g4.setModelName("BHC Base");
                                            g4.setYear(cell.getRichStringCellValue().toString());
                                        }
                                        //System.out.print(cell.getRichStringCellValue() + " ");

                                    }
                                    if (ActulaColINdex <= 30 && ActulaColINdex >= 26) //BHC Severly Adverse
                                    {
                                        if (ActulaColINdex == 26)
                                        {
                                            g5.setVolumeName(ModelName);
                                            g5.setModelName("BHC Severely Adverse");
                                            g5.setYear(cell.getRichStringCellValue().toString());
                                        }
                                        //System.out.print(cell.getRichStringCellValue() + " ");

                                    }
                                } else if (cell.getCellType() == XSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC)
                                {
                                    if (ActulaColINdex <= 5 && ActulaColINdex >= 1) //Base 
                                    {
                                        if (ActulaColINdex == 2)
                                        {
                                            g1.setSasmodel(cell.getNumericCellValue());
                                        }

                                    }
                                    if (ActulaColINdex <= 11 && ActulaColINdex >= 7) //Adverse 
                                    {
                                        if (ActulaColINdex == 8)
                                        {
                                            g2.setSasmodel(cell.getNumericCellValue());
                                        }

                                    }
                                    if (ActulaColINdex <= 17 && ActulaColINdex >= 13) //Severly Adverse 
                                    {
                                        if (ActulaColINdex == 14)
                                        {
                                            g3.setSasmodel(cell.getNumericCellValue());
                                        }

                                    }
                                    if (ActulaColINdex <= 23 && ActulaColINdex >= 19) //BHC Base 
                                    {
                                        if (ActulaColINdex == 20)
                                        {
                                            g4.setSasmodel(cell.getNumericCellValue());
                                        }

                                    }
                                    if (ActulaColINdex <= 30 && ActulaColINdex >= 26) //BHC Severly Advrse 
                                    {
                                        if (ActulaColINdex == 27)
                                        {
                                            g5.setSasmodel(cell.getNumericCellValue());
                                        }

                                    }
                                } else if (cell.getCellType() == XSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_FORMULA)
                                {
                                    switch (cell.getCachedFormulaResultType())
                                    {
                                        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                                        {
                                            if (ActulaColINdex <= 5 && ActulaColINdex >= 1) //Base 
                                            {
                                                if (ActulaColINdex == 3)
                                                {
                                                    g1.setXxcelmodel(cell.getNumericCellValue());
                                                }
                                                if (ActulaColINdex == 4)
                                                {
                                                    g1.setDiff(cell.getNumericCellValue());
                                                }
                                                if (ActulaColINdex == 5)
                                                {
                                                    g1.setDiffper(cell.getNumericCellValue());
                                                    Basemap.add(g1);
                                                }

                                            }
                                            if (ActulaColINdex <= 11 && ActulaColINdex >= 7) //Adverse 
                                            {
                                                if (ActulaColINdex == 9)
                                                {
                                                    g2.setXxcelmodel(cell.getNumericCellValue());
                                                }
                                                if (ActulaColINdex == 10)
                                                {
                                                    g2.setDiff(cell.getNumericCellValue());
                                                }
                                                if (ActulaColINdex == 11)
                                                {
                                                    g2.setDiffper(cell.getNumericCellValue());
                                                    Adversemap.add(g2);
                                                }

                                            }
                                            if (ActulaColINdex <= 17 && ActulaColINdex >= 13) //SeverlyAdverse 
                                            {
                                                if (ActulaColINdex == 15)
                                                {
                                                    g3.setXxcelmodel(cell.getNumericCellValue());
                                                }
                                                if (ActulaColINdex == 16)
                                                {
                                                    g3.setDiff(cell.getNumericCellValue());
                                                }
                                                if (ActulaColINdex == 17)
                                                {
                                                    g3.setDiffper(cell.getNumericCellValue());
                                                    SeverelyAdversemap.add(g3);
                                                }

                                            }
                                            if (ActulaColINdex <= 23 && ActulaColINdex >= 19)//BHC Base 
                                            {
                                                if (ActulaColINdex == 21)
                                                {
                                                    g4.setXxcelmodel(cell.getNumericCellValue());
                                                }
                                                if (ActulaColINdex == 22)
                                                {
                                                    g4.setDiff(cell.getNumericCellValue());
                                                }
                                                if (ActulaColINdex == 23)
                                                {
                                                    g4.setDiffper(cell.getNumericCellValue());
                                                    BHCBasemap.add(g4);
                                                }

                                            }
                                            if (ActulaColINdex <= 30 && ActulaColINdex >= 26)//BHC Severly Adverse
                                            {
                                                if (ActulaColINdex == 28)
                                                {
                                                    g5.setXxcelmodel(cell.getNumericCellValue());
                                                }
                                                if (ActulaColINdex == 29)
                                                {
                                                    g5.setDiff(cell.getNumericCellValue());
                                                }
                                                if (ActulaColINdex == 30)
                                                {
                                                    g5.setDiffper(cell.getNumericCellValue());
                                                    BHCSeverelyAdversemap.add(g5);
                                                }

                                            }

                                        }
                                        break;
                                        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                                        {
                                            if (ActulaColINdex <= 5 && ActulaColINdex >= 1)//Base 
                                            {
                                                if (ActulaColINdex == 3)
                                                {
                                                    g1.setXxcelmodel(cell.getNumericCellValue());
                                                }
                                                if (ActulaColINdex == 4)
                                                {
                                                    g1.setDiff(cell.getNumericCellValue());
                                                }
                                                if (ActulaColINdex == 5)
                                                {
                                                    g1.setDiffper(cell.getNumericCellValue());
                                                    Basemap.add(g1);
                                                }

                                            }
                                            if (ActulaColINdex <= 11 && ActulaColINdex >= 7) //Adverse 
                                            {
                                                if (ActulaColINdex == 9)
                                                {
                                                    g2.setXxcelmodel(cell.getNumericCellValue());
                                                }
                                                if (ActulaColINdex == 10)
                                                {
                                                    g2.setDiff(cell.getNumericCellValue());
                                                }
                                                if (ActulaColINdex == 11)
                                                {
                                                    g2.setDiffper(cell.getNumericCellValue());
                                                    Adversemap.add(g2);
                                                }

                                            }
                                            if (ActulaColINdex <= 17 && ActulaColINdex >= 13) //SeverlyAdverse 
                                            {
                                                if (ActulaColINdex == 15)
                                                {
                                                    g3.setXxcelmodel(cell.getNumericCellValue());
                                                }
                                                if (ActulaColINdex == 16)
                                                {
                                                    g3.setDiff(cell.getNumericCellValue());
                                                }
                                                if (ActulaColINdex == 17)
                                                {
                                                    g3.setDiffper(cell.getNumericCellValue());
                                                    SeverelyAdversemap.add(g3);
                                                }
                                                ActulaColINdex++;
                                            }
                                            if (ActulaColINdex <= 23 && ActulaColINdex >= 19)//BHC Base 
                                            {
                                                if (ActulaColINdex == 21)
                                                {
                                                    g4.setXxcelmodel(cell.getNumericCellValue());
                                                }
                                                if (ActulaColINdex == 22)
                                                {
                                                    g4.setDiff(cell.getNumericCellValue());
                                                }
                                                if (ActulaColINdex == 23)
                                                {
                                                    g4.setDiffper(cell.getNumericCellValue());
                                                    BHCBasemap.add(g4);
                                                }

                                            }
                                            if (ActulaColINdex <= 30 && ActulaColINdex >= 26)//BHC Severly Adverse
                                            {
                                                if (ActulaColINdex == 28)
                                                {
                                                    g5.setXxcelmodel(cell.getNumericCellValue());
                                                }
                                                if (ActulaColINdex == 29)
                                                {
                                                    g5.setDiff(cell.getNumericCellValue());
                                                }
                                                if (ActulaColINdex == 30)
                                                {
                                                    g5.setDiffper(cell.getNumericCellValue());
                                                    BHCSeverelyAdversemap.add(g5);
                                                }

                                            }
                                        }
                                        break;
                                    }
                                } else
                                {
                                    //U Can Handel Boolean, Formula, Errors
                                }
                            }
                            System.out.println();
                        }
                        wb.close();
                        fs.close();
                        System.out.println("-----------------------Base----------------------");
                        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                        Connection con;
                        con = getConnection();
                        Statement st = con.createStatement();
                        String sql1 = "delete from outputtable where modelid=" + modelid;
                        int flag1 = st.executeUpdate(sql1);

                        for (int i = 0; i < Basemap.size(); i++)
                        {
                            graphdata g = (graphdata) Basemap.get(i);
                            String sql = "INSERT INTO outputtable (VolumeName,ModelName,year,sasmodel,excelmodel,diff,diffper,modelid)"
                                    + " VALUES ('" + g.getVolumeName() + "','" + g.getModelName() + "','" + g.getYear() + "', " + g.getSasmodel() + ", " + g.getXxcelmodel() + ", " + g.getDiff() + ", " + g.getDiffper() + ", " + modelid + ")";
                            st.executeUpdate(sql);
                            System.out.println(g.getVolumeName() + "" + g.getYear() + "" + g.getModelName() + "" + g.getSasmodel() + "" + g.getXxcelmodel());
                        }
                        System.out.println("-----------------------Advrse----------------------");
                        for (int i = 0; i < Adversemap.size(); i++)
                        {
                            graphdata g = (graphdata) Adversemap.get(i);
                            String sql = "INSERT INTO outputtable (`outputtable`.`VolumeName`,`outputtable`.`ModelName`,`outputtable`.`year`,`outputtable`.`sasmodel`,`outputtable`.`excelmodel`,`outputtable`.`diff`,`outputtable`.`diffper`,`outputtable`.`modelid`)"
                                    + " VALUES ('" + g.getVolumeName() + "','" + g.getModelName() + "','" + g.getYear() + "', " + g.getSasmodel() + ", " + g.getXxcelmodel() + ", " + g.getDiff() + ", " + g.getDiffper() + ", " + modelid + ")";
                            st.executeUpdate(sql);
                            System.out.println(g.getVolumeName() + "" + g.getYear() + "" + g.getModelName() + "" + g.getSasmodel() + "" + g.getXxcelmodel());
                        }
                        System.out.println("-----------------------Severly Advers----------------------");
                        for (int i = 0; i < SeverelyAdversemap.size(); i++)
                        {
                            graphdata g = (graphdata) SeverelyAdversemap.get(i);
                            String sql = "INSERT INTO outputtable (`outputtable`.`VolumeName`,`outputtable`.`ModelName`,`outputtable`.`year`,`outputtable`.`sasmodel`,`outputtable`.`excelmodel`,`outputtable`.`diff`,`outputtable`.`diffper`,`outputtable`.`modelid`)"
                                    + " VALUES ('" + g.getVolumeName() + "','" + g.getModelName() + "','" + g.getYear() + "', " + g.getSasmodel() + ", " + g.getXxcelmodel() + ", " + g.getDiff() + ", " + g.getDiffper() + ", " + modelid + ")";
                            st.executeUpdate(sql);
                            System.out.println(g.getVolumeName() + "" + g.getYear() + "" + g.getModelName() + "" + g.getSasmodel() + "" + g.getXxcelmodel());
                        }
                        System.out.println("-----------------------BHC Base----------------------");
                        for (int i = 0; i < BHCBasemap.size(); i++)
                        {
                            graphdata g = (graphdata) BHCBasemap.get(i);
                            String sql = "INSERT INTO outputtable (`outputtable`.`VolumeName`,`outputtable`.`ModelName`,`outputtable`.`year`,`outputtable`.`sasmodel`,`outputtable`.`excelmodel`,`outputtable`.`diff`,`outputtable`.`diffper`,`outputtable`.`modelid`)"
                                    + " VALUES ('" + g.getVolumeName() + "','" + g.getModelName() + "','" + g.getYear() + "', " + g.getSasmodel() + ", " + g.getXxcelmodel() + ", " + g.getDiff() + ", " + g.getDiffper() + ", " + modelid + ")";
                            st.executeUpdate(sql);
                            System.out.println(g.getVolumeName() + "" + g.getYear() + "" + g.getModelName() + "" + g.getSasmodel() + "" + g.getXxcelmodel());
                        }
                        System.out.println("-----------------------BHC Severly Adve----------------------");
                        for (int i = 0; i < BHCSeverelyAdversemap.size(); i++)
                        {
                            graphdata g = (graphdata) BHCSeverelyAdversemap.get(i);
                            String sql = "INSERT INTO outputtable (`outputtable`.`VolumeName`,`outputtable`.`ModelName`,`outputtable`.`year`,`outputtable`.`sasmodel`,`outputtable`.`excelmodel`,`outputtable`.`diff`,`outputtable`.`diffper`,`outputtable`.`modelid`)"
                                    + " VALUES ('" + g.getVolumeName() + "','" + g.getModelName() + "','" + g.getYear() + "', " + g.getSasmodel() + ", " + g.getXxcelmodel() + ", " + g.getDiff() + ", " + g.getDiffper() + ", " + modelid + ")";
                            st.executeUpdate(sql);
                            System.out.println(g.getVolumeName() + "" + g.getYear() + "" + g.getModelName() + "" + g.getSasmodel() + "" + g.getXxcelmodel());
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        return Response.status(401)
                                .header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
                                .header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "origin, content-type, accept, authorization")
                                .header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true")
                                .header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS, HEAD")
                                .header("Access-Control-Max-Age", "1209600")
                                .entity("[{\"Success\":\"Error\"}]")
                                .build();
                    }
                    return Response.status(200)
                            .header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
                            .header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "origin, content-type, accept, authorization")
                            .header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true")
                            .header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS, HEAD")
                            .header("Access-Control-Max-Age", "1209600")
                            .entity("[{\"Success\":\"Yes\"}]")
                            .build();
                }
```

Problem is :- While reading second sheet using apache poi in java, it read previous data not the updated data after calculation.even if `Model.xlsx` contain updated data java reads only previous data.This is very strange find me any solution.

Kindly please assist me.

Thanks.

Comment: I haven't looked at the code yet but here is a guess, you have not saved/closed the `Model.xlsx` file from the first function after modifying it.

Comment: I have tried with close(), but still not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use Aspose.Cells for Java to implement your solution, then following articles will be helpful for you.

- http://www.aspose.com/docs/display/cellsjava/Copying+and+Moving+Worksheets
- http://www.aspose.com/docs/display/cellsjava/Combine+Multiple+Workbooks+into+a+Single+Workbook
- http://www.aspose.com/docs/display/cellsjava/Combine+Multiple+Worksheets+into+a+Single+Worksheet
- http://www.aspose.com/docs/display/cellsjava/Accessing+Cells+of+a+Worksheet
- http://www.aspose.com/docs/display/cellsjava/Adding+Data+to+Cells
- http://www.aspose.com/docs/display/cellsjava/Retrieving+Data+from+Cells
- http://www.aspose.com/docs/display/cellsjava/Importing+Data+to+Worksheets
- http://www.aspose.com/docs/display/cellsjava/Exporting+Data+from+Worksheets

*Note: I am working as Developer Evangelist at Aspose*

Comment: Thanks It Work With Aspose.